# Meaning of symbol big wedge in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I am reading algebraic geometry from a course notes and I am struck on this notation.

> Question : Consider this theorem: " The embedding of Gr(k,n) into projective space is defined by $ W \to $ the line$ \bigwedge^k W \subset \bigwedge^k V$".

In the course notes the meaning of the notation $\bigwedge^k$ is not given. Can you please let me know the meaning of this notation?

Comment: [Exterior power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Exterior_power)

Comment: Big wedge is a symbol from *linear algebra* in fact.